# Pause menu without camera moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started programing in Unity and C# this week and i have a small problem, i cant get the camera to stop in the pause menu. I managed to stop time but the camera is still moving. I tried to use some codes from youtube but they dont work :/ Here is my PlayerMovement and Pause Men script, it has some polish words there, but most are for height,speed etc klawiatura=keybord and mysz=mouse.

**PlayerMovement.cs**

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Obiekt odpowiedzialny za ruch gracza.
    public CharacterController characterControler;

    public float predkoscPoruszania = 9.0f;
    public float wysokoscSkoku = 7.0f;
    public float aktualnaWysokoscSkoku = 0f;
    public float predkoscBiegania = 7.0f;
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;        
    public float czuloscMyszki = 3.0f;
    public float myszGoraDol = 0.0f;
    public float zakresMyszyGoraDol = 90.0f;

    void Start()
    {
     characterControler = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        klawiatura();
        myszka();

    }

    private void klawiatura()
    {

        float rochPrzodTyl = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * predkoscPoruszania;

        float rochLewoPrawo = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * predkoscPoruszania;

        if (characterControler.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            aktualnaWysokoscSkoku = wysokoscSkoku;
        }
        else if (!characterControler.isGrounded)
        {
            aktualnaWysokoscSkoku += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        Debug.Log(Physics.gravity.y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left shift"))
        {
            predkoscPoruszania += predkoscBiegania;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp("left shift"))
        {
            predkoscPoruszania -= predkoscBiegania;
        }
        Vector3 ruch = new Vector3(rochLewoPrawo, aktualnaWysokoscSkoku, rochPrzodTyl);
        ruch = transform.rotation * ruch;
        characterControler.Move(ruch * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void myszka()
    {
         if (!GameIsPaused)
            {
            float myszLewoPrawo = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * czuloscMyszki;
            transform.Rotate(0, myszLewoPrawo, 0);

            myszGoraDol -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * czuloscMyszki;
            myszGoraDol = Mathf.Clamp(myszGoraDol, -zakresMyszyGoraDol, zakresMyszyGoraDol);
            Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(myszGoraDol, 0, 0);
            }
    }

}
```

** PauseMenu.cs** *I got this from YouTube and changed it a bit!*

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    private void Start()
    {
        Resume();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
          {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }


   void Pause()
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;

    }

    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menu6");
    }

    public void QuitMenu()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }


}
```

---

Edit:

So i changed the mouse part in the first script but it still doesnt work.

```cs
private void myszka()
{
    if (!GameIsPaused)
    {
        float myszLewoPrawo = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * czuloscMyszki;
        transform.Rotate(0, myszLewoPrawo, 0);

        myszGoraDol -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * czuloscMyszki;
        myszGoraDol = Mathf.Clamp(myszGoraDol, -zakresMyszyGoraDol, zakresMyszyGoraDol);
        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(myszGoraDol, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your camera script, check if `!GameIsPaused` before calling the methods that move your camera.

Comment: @IanH. i edited the script with that if and it still doesnt work, if i do it without ! then the camera freezes but in the game not on the menu.

Comment: Can you update the code in the question?

Comment: @IanH. Just updated it, I basicly added if (!GameIsPaused) in the last part and public static bool GameIsPaused = false;  at the top of the script in characterControler

Comment: You have to check `PauseMenu.GameIsPaused`, remove the other `static bool GameIsPaused` from the player script!

Comment: @IanH. It worked ! Thank you so much for the help !

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer, in case any else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `!PauseMenu.GameIsPaused` before moving the camera in your update function. That way, the camera will only receive movement commands if the game is *not* paused.

```cs
private void myszka()
{
    if (!PauseMenu.GameIsPaused)
    {
        float myszLewoPrawo = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * czuloscMyszki;
        transform.Rotate(0, myszLewoPrawo, 0);

        myszGoraDol -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * czuloscMyszki;
        myszGoraDol = Mathf.Clamp(myszGoraDol, -zakresMyszyGoraDol, zakresMyszyGoraDol);
        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(myszGoraDol, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле всё элементарно:

```
    void IsPaused()
{
    if (Time.timeScale == 0f)
    {
        sensivity = 0f;
    }
    else
    {
        sensivity = 8f;
    }
```

IsPaused ставится в Update и всё.

Comment: please use english